# how to manage Big Database sites? My site have 20k pages and DB size is 3gb

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have a site which has 20k+ pages (not posts) and increasing daily. I want to know how I can manage without increasing my DB size, which is 3gb right now. due to that I can't open my Pages tab on WordPress and showing me 504 gateway error.

Memory Already set on 700mb+

Already optimized with wp rocket and DB optimize plugin

Comment: More data is going to equal more space required, there’s no real way around that. But there are other options. Indexing and/or partitioning your database to improve speed is one. Another is to archive your older data (e.g. your old pages) (if that is an option for your scenario).

Comment: Hi @Treebasher thanks for commenting, but I want to keep my pages live on site and want to know is there any way to make portion in the database so the database will stay small.

Comment: A better question might be: "Is there a way to make wordpress not crash on my pages tab even though I have 20k+ pages, considering that wordpress should be able to [support a million times](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/274099) that much"?